if html2pdf.js support arabic, why i am experiencing characters appearing detached or incorrectly rendered?
this my js code that i use, i can download the file normally, everything is organized correctly, but the language appears incorrectly, as it appears detached and incorrectly rendered.
let downloadPDF = document.getElementById("download");
downloadPDF.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(); 

  let certif = document.getElementById('certificate-content');

  html2canvas(certif, {
    scale: 2,
    useCORS: true,
    logging: true,
    foreignObjectRendering: true,
    letterRendering: 1,
    allowTaint: true,
    async: false,

  }).then(canvas => {
    let imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.98);
    let pdf = new jsPDF('landscape', 'px', 'a4');
    let pageWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.width;
    let pageHeight = pdf.internal.pageSize.height;
    let imgWidth = pageWidth;
    let imgHeight = (canvas.height * imgWidth) / canvas.width;

    pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);

    // Download the PDF
    pdf.save('Udemy-certificate.pdf');
  }).catch(err => {
    console.error("Error generating PDF:", err);
  });
});

